# Auto-Complete with Emacs 24 doesn't work with Java, C or C++ modes

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, emacs24

I installed auto-complete using the marmalade repo. Everything installed correctly and after moving stuff around I managed to start up and run auto-correct without any errors with the following code in my init.el:

```
;; auto-complete
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete/dict")
(ac-config-default)
```

Now I can use auto-complete with no hick-ups with Emacs Lisp but whenever I use any other mode, like, Java, C, or C++ it doesn't work at all.

I have yasnippet installed too (it works perfectly), not sure if that might have anything to do with it. Here's the relevant code in my init.el:

```
;;yasnippet
(add-to-list 'load-path
              "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
```

I am in the process of learning Emacs and currently I'm still a noob. I've been looking all over the documentation and SO but haven't found anything. I'd really appreciate any help whatsoever on this.

Comment: Is autocomplete mode activating at all for those C-lang modes? `AC` should be visible in the modeline in those modes.

Comment: @ChrisBarrett See my comment to your answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to add completion sources. Here's what's in my config:

```
(set-default 'ac-sources
             '(ac-source-abbrev
               ac-source-dictionary
               ac-source-yasnippet
               ac-source-words-in-buffer
               ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers
               ac-source-semantic))
```

*Update*: `ac-config-default` should cover this, but if autocomplete isn't activating for those modes, try putting the following in your init.el:

```
(dolist (m '(c-mode c++-mode java-mode))
  (add-to-list 'ac-modes m))

(global-auto-complete-mode t)
```

*Update2*: I've posted a [gist](https://gist.github.com/4704610) that adapts your init.el to pull autocomplete using `package-install`.

I can't tell what version of auto-complete you were referencing, but the latest is working fine for me.

[image: C-mode with working auto-completions]

Comment: Is that your auto-complete-config or init.el/.emacs?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I am on Windows, not sure that matters. By the way, thanks for the answer, appreciate you trying to help.

Comment: With your suggestions now its activating on all modes with the little AC written but its not working like it works with Elisp. No pop ups with suggestions, nothing. PS Already upvoted your answer or I'd do it again :D

Comment: Do you have your init.el on GitHub?

Comment: No I don't, sorry. Never put anything up on GitHub. Let me figure it out and put it up and then I'll report back here. Thanks for helping out raelly.

Comment: If your init.el is short enough, you could put it in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/), which is a quick way of sharing code snippets.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Here's my init file: https://gist.github.com/96d701f5d3f106ab949b It might be a mess since I'm still learning. :D

Comment: I tried your changes (thanks for the tip on fetching yasnippet and auto-complete from the repos, btw) and it didn't work. Went over to my mac to see if it would work, and it didn't. Tried the exact same thing as suggested by the image and it didn't work so I'm accepting your answer since I can't put my finger on what could be wrong. Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Comment: just want to add that this didn't work for me... Emacs 24.2.2, auto-complete v1.3.1. and no config for yasnippet at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have exact same issue as you. Emacs-Lisp works perfect with auto-complete but C, C++ doesn't work. After trying with various combination, I find out that commenting out yasnippet from .emacs solve my issue. Hope this could help you. My auto-complete version is 1.3.1.